# Consequences of failing to .Close ADODB.Connection?

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection, adodb

I inherited an ASP site whose ASP pages liberally include a large config file that, among many other things, opens two ADODB connections to MS SQL servers via:

```
SET Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Open "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
```

I appears that on many pages these connections are never closed (though it's hard to be certain because the code is a maze of ASP `#include`s).  In contrast, on some there is a very clear `<% CONNECTION.CLOSE %>`.

What is the consequence of failing to close these connections by the end of a GET?

Comment: see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380185/is-it-necessary-to-close-an-adodb-recordset-object-before-setting-it-to-nothing

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, @John.